# google maps api gradle dependencies failed to resolve

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-play-services

It's showing me an error of failure to resolve dependency:

```
Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.0
```

These are the dependencies i'm using:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.0'

}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 11):

To use the **11.4.0** you have to add maven { url "https://maven.google.com" } to your `build.gradle` file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: tried it. but it still showed an error.

Comment: @HadiAbu Post your updated build.gradle and the error message.

Comment: It worked.
before i had two different dependency versions for maps and locations:
 
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'.

but i changed it to be of the same version and it worked:

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.0'

Answer (score 4):

turned out that the google-maps dependency should be:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
```

and not

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.0'
```

Comment: It is not the reason of your issue. The 11.4.0 exists but it requires the new google maven repo.